# No routes matched location

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

hello I have an error with the React Router routes, mainly it told me that the routes do not match.

I have a route that leads to a component with two other routes and they do not match.

MainRouter

```
<AuthContext.Provider value={{
    user,
    setUser
  }}>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={ <AppRouter /> }>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
  </AuthContext.Provider
```

Routers

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/profile' element={
    <PrivateRoute isAuth={user.logged}>
      <ProfileScreen />
    </PrivateRoute>
  } />
  <Route path='/' element={
    <PrivateRoute isAuth={user.logged}>
      <HomeScreen />
    </PrivateRoute>
  } />
  <Route path="/auth/*" element={
    <PublicRoute isAuth={user.logged}>
      <AuthRouter setChecking={setChecking} />
    </PublicRoute>
  } />
  <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/' />}/>
</Routes>
```

AuthRouter

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='login' element={<LoginScreen setChecking={setChecking} />} />
  <Route path='welcome' element={<WelcomeScreen />} />
  <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/login' />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

I believe I've reproduced the issue you face in a running codesandbox. If you read all the errors (2x) they inform you what the issue is and how to resolve it.

Errors:

> You rendered descendant `<Routes>` (or called `useRoutes()`) at "/"
> (under `<Route path="/">`) but the parent route path has no trailing
> "*". This means if you navigate deeper, the parent won't match anymore
> and therefore the child routes will never render.
>
> Please change the parent `<Route path="/">` to `<Route path="*">`.
> in Routes (created by AppRouter)
> in AppRouter (created by MainRouter)
> in MainRouter (created by App)
> in App

and

> No routes matched location "/auth/login"
> in Routes (created by MainRouter)
> in MainRouter (created by App)
> in App

Both errors are resolved by fixing the root `MainRouter` component to append the trailing `"*"` wildcard character to allow further matching and rendering of nested routes. *Note that this assumes your private/public route wrappers are using correct redirect paths.**

```
<AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/*" element={<AppRouter />} /> // <-- allow nested matching
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
</AuthContext.Provider>
```

* Example `PrivateRoute` and `PublicRoute` components. Note that `PrivateRoute` is redirecting to `"/auth/login"` ***and not*** `"/login"`, which may be part of the cause of the second error.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children, isAuth }) =>
  isAuth ? children : <Navigate to="/auth/login" replace />;

const PublicRoute = ({ children, isAuth }) =>
  isAuth ? <Navigate to="/" replace /> : children;
```

Since you didn't clarify exactly which locations didn't have a matching route, the `"/login"` route of your `AuthRouter` seems a good candidate for the offender since it's rendered on `"/auth/*"` by `AppRouter`. It also has an invalid redirect target for unknown paths; it's redirecting to a root `"/login"` path that doesn't exist. Update this redirect to `"/auth/login"`.

```
const AuthRouter = ({ setChecking }) => (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="login" element={<LoginScreen setChecking={setChecking} />} />
    <Route path="welcome" element={<WelcomeScreen />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/auth/login" />} />
  </Routes>
);
```

[image: Edit no-routes-matched-location]

Comment: Edit on CodeSandBox link is awesome mate, I appreciate the creativity 